# Functional equations in one variable..

Tags: functional-equations

How do you solve the functional equation involving only one variable...what if and if not given that $f(x)$ is a polynomial...

Say for example $f(x)=f(x-1) +2x$

Comment: If $f$ is a polynomial it has degree $2$. Write $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and find $a$, $b$ and $c$

Comment: How do you know if is 2degree

Comment: How do you know it's not a transcendental function of some sort?  Or algebraic of higher degree?

Comment: Would you please be more specific about your question and tag?

Comment: @RakibulIslamPrince like?

Comment: Let $f$ be a n-degree polynomial, so is $f(x-1)$. Then $f(x)-f(x-1)$ is at most a $n-1$ degree polynomial. Since $f(x)-f(x-1)=2x$ then $n-1\le1\iff n\le2$. Write $f(x)$ as a 2-degree standard polynomial. If the degree is less than 2, some coefficient will cancel

Comment: @RakibulIslamPrince hmm....the tag shouldn’t be calculus I hope....sorry...what it could be.. I will change..............if 2 variables are involved then some general method following calculus is done

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE fine

Comment: wait a bit more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a finite difference equation of the first order, and it is linear.

Hence you solve the homogeneous part of the equation,

$$f(x)=f(x-1)$$ which is simply $f(x)=c$.

Next you find a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation. As the RHS is a linear polynomial, you know that a quadratic polynomial  will do and

$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-1)^2+b(x-1)+c+2x$$ gives $a=b=1$.

Hence

$$f(x)=x^2+x+c$$ which can be written $$f(x)=x^2+x+f(0).$$

---

**Technical note:**

If no other condition is given on $f$, the values of $f$ are only constrained one unit apart and the constant can differ when the fractional parts differ. Hence the general solution is actually

$$f(x)=x^2+x+f(\{ x\})$$

where $f$ is any function in $[0,1)$.

An example solution:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate the general case...

Comment: @pss1: ooops, sorry, I fixed the typo.